# Get Facebook locale before login or even loading the SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, locale, facebook-canvas

I'm creating a multilingual Facebook Canvas game. I want it to use the user's Facebook locale as its own locale.

I can easily get the locale of a user who is logged in and has authed my app. However:

- I need the locale before a new user authenticates my app, because I want to show some text before this option is given.
- In fact, I need it before I've even loaded the Javascript SDK. This is because a locale must be given when loading this (e.g. https://connect.facebook.net/**en_US**/all.js)

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In fact, I need it before I've even loaded the Javascript SDK.

Parse the signed_request, that gets passed to your app when it gets loaded into canvas, server-side: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/

Comment: I have no server-side code (at that point), just an Nginx server with some magic to accept POST requests to static pages. I'll see if I can somehow get the signed request from that.

Comment: Well I wrote a small bit of server code. Annoying, but it works.